Class 'Object' has no method named 'getRunningAppProcesses'

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL
Java_com_ghost_hooker_Hooker_isAppRunning(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jstring package_name) {
const char *pkg_name = env->GetStringUTFChars(package_name, nullptr);
LOGI("Checking if package %s is running", pkg_name);

// Get the Context class and the getSystemService method ID
jclass hookerClass = env->GetObjectClass(thiz);
jfieldID contextField = env->GetFieldID(hookerClass, "context", "Landroid/content/Context;");
jobject context = env->GetObjectField(thiz, contextField);

jclass contextClass = env->GetObjectClass(context);

// Use Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE
jfieldID activityServiceField = env->GetStaticFieldID(contextClass, "ACTIVITY_SERVICE", "Ljava/lang/String;");
auto activityService = (jstring) env->GetStaticObjectField(contextClass, activityServiceField);

jmethodID getSystemService = env->GetMethodID(contextClass, "getSystemService", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;");
jobject activityManager = env->CallObjectMethod(context, getSystemService, activityService);

if (activityManager == nullptr) {
    LOGE("Failed to get ActivityManager");
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(package_name, pkg_name);
    return JNI_FALSE;
} else {
    LOGI("ActivityManager object address: %p", activityManager);
}

// Get the ActivityManager class
jclass activityManagerClass = env->GetObjectClass(activityManager);

// Log available methods in ActivityManager for debugging
jclass classClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/Class");
jmethodID getMethods = env->GetMethodID(classClass, "getMethods", "()[Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;");
auto methodsArray = (jobjectArray)env->CallObjectMethod(activityManagerClass, getMethods);

jint methodsCount = env->GetArrayLength(methodsArray);
LOGI("ActivityManager has %d methods", methodsCount);

for (jint i = 0; i < methodsCount; i++) {
    jobject method = env->GetObjectArrayElement(methodsArray, i);
    jclass methodClass = env->GetObjectClass(method);

    jmethodID getName = env->GetMethodID(methodClass, "getName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
    auto methodName = (jstring)env->CallObjectMethod(method, getName);

    const char *methodNameChars = env->GetStringUTFChars(methodName, nullptr);
    LOGI("Method %d: %s", i, methodNameChars);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(methodName, methodNameChars);
}

// Get the getRunningAppProcesses method
jmethodID getRunningAppProcesses = env->GetMethodID(activityManagerClass, "getRunningAppProcesses", "()Ljava/util/List;"); <== ERROR HERE
if (getRunningAppProcesses == nullptr) {
    LOGE("Method getRunningAppProcesses not found");
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(package_name, pkg_name);
    return JNI_FALSE;
}

jobject runningAppProcesses = env->CallObjectMethod(activityManager,getRunningAppProcesses);
if (runningAppProcesses == nullptr) {
    LOGE("Failed to get running app processes");
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(package_name, pkg_name);
    return JNI_FALSE;
}

// Iterate through the running app processes
jclass listClass = env->GetObjectClass(runningAppProcesses);
jmethodID listGet = env->GetMethodID(listClass, "get", "(I)Ljava/lang/Object;");
jmethodID listSize = env->GetMethodID(listClass, "size", "()I");

jint size = env->CallIntMethod(runningAppProcesses, listSize);
LOGI("Number of running app processes: %d", size);

jboolean isRunning = JNI_FALSE;

for (jint i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    jobject appProcessInfo = env->CallObjectMethod(runningAppProcesses, listGet, i);
    jclass appProcessInfoClass = env->GetObjectClass(appProcessInfo);
    jfieldID processNameField = env->GetFieldID(appProcessInfoClass, "processName", "Ljava/lang/String;");
    auto processName = (jstring)env->GetObjectField(appProcessInfo, processNameField);

    const char *proc_name = env->GetStringUTFChars(processName, nullptr);
    LOGI("Running process %d: %s", i, proc_name);

    if (strcmp(proc_name, pkg_name) == 0) {
        isRunning = JNI_TRUE;
        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(processName, proc_name);
        break;
    }

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(processName, proc_name);
}

env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(package_name, pkg_name);
return isRunning;

}
in log cat method exist
Method 28: getRecentTasks
Method 29: getRunningAppProcesses
Method 30: getRunningServiceControlPanel

error in android studio Class 'Object' has no method named 'getRunningAppProcesses'.
How to fix it?
I hope the problem can be solved here
